# Is it possible to loop over a comma delimited list inside a MySQL SELECT?

Tags: mysql, regex, select, stored-procedures, loops

I need to select all products from a MySQL table which meet size/quantity pairs submitted by a user.

For example, I end up with

```
S  = 2
M  = 2
L  = 3
XL = 1
```

Which I'm getting as two delimiter strings like so:

```
S,M,L,XL 
2,2,3,1
```

My database query is currently in a Coldfusion8 page, where I just loop through the 2d array I create from both strings and do a loop inside my SELECT statement

```
 <cfloop from="1" to="#array.length#" index="i">
 OR  ( size = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cfsql_varchar" value="#var.lotArray[i][1]#"> AND qty  >= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cfsql_varchar" value="#var.lotArray[i][2]#"> )
 </cfloop>
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to do this in MySQL INSIDE a SELECT in a stored procedure? I guess I could loop through the string length and SELECT ONCE per iteration, but this will be a lot of resultsets and I'm not sure how to group these together then. I also looked at regex, but I'm not sure how to SELECT with two regex strings and both strings needing to correlate (M=2, L=3...)

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: It is probably possible to do this with intensive use of functions, but your performance will be really bad. Please, honor the first NF (atomic values).

Comment: [Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms) - It has to due with database normalization, which _"is the process of organizing the fields and tables of a relational database to minimize redundancy and dependency."_ Following normalization guidelines typically will result in much greater performance.

Comment: You should either change your schema, or continue to just do it in the app code like you are. Trying to do this with mysql will make an extremely bloated, difficult-to-read, and inefficient query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really getting fond of MySQL... seems like it does not work. I had hoped to be able to at least loop through my variable name using ELT like so:

```
 ELT( loopcounter, passed_sizes )
```

With the loopcounter going from 1,2,3... and passed_sizes being a string like 'S','M','L','XL', but I guess you can't construct elements like that either.

So I ended up doing the excessive-code solution:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT art.a, art.v, art.c
    FROM arts AS art
    WHERE ( (filter = '') AND (1=1)
        OR art.d = filter
        )          
    AND ( (size_1 = '') AND (1=1) OR ( art.size = size_1 AND art.qty >= qty_1 ) )
    AND ( (size_2 = '') AND (1=1) OR ( art.size = size_2 AND art.qty >= qty_2 ) )
    AND ( (size_3 = '') AND (1=1) OR ( art.size = size_3 AND art.qty >= qty_3 ) )
    AND ( (size_4 = '') AND (1=1) OR ( art.size = size_4 AND art.qty >= qty_4 ) )
    AND ( (size_5 = '') AND (1=1) OR ( art.size = size_5 AND art.qty >= qty_5 ) )
    AND ( (size_6 = '') AND (1=1) OR ( art.size = size_6 AND art.qty >= qty_6 ) )
    AND ( (size_7 = '') AND (1=1) OR ( art.size = size_7 AND art.qty >= qty_7 ) )
    AND ( (size_8 = '') AND (1=1) OR ( art.size = size_8 AND art.qty >= qty_8 ) )
    AND ( (size_9 = '') AND (1=1) OR ( art.size = size_9 AND art.qty >= qty_9 ) )
    AND ( (size_10 = '') AND (1=1) OR ( art.size = size_10 AND art.qty >= qty_10 ) )
    GROUP BY art.a, art.v, art.c
    HAVING anzahl = length;
 END
```

and passing in 22 parameters instead of a two strings. Readable but boy do I miss easy to use loops... If anyone knows an easier implementation, please post as answer. Thanks!